# Associative Array for places

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 2 arrays that I have made into an Associative Array. I also have combinations of winner positions = ie '1,2', '2,3', '1,3'. What I need to do is replace the position numbers with jersey numbers and put back into the same configuration as the combinations were written. For Example, I've set up my jersey, position, combo, and associative array:

```
$jersey = array('3','1','5','4');
$position = array('1','2','3','4');
$AssocArr = array_combine($position, $jersey);
$Combo = array('1,2','2,3','1,3');
```

I've set up a function to get the values from the keys:

```
function getVals($finishPosMap, $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
         $output[] = $finishPosMap[$key];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The part I'm having issue with is putting them back into an array with the values instead of keys. This is what I've done so far:

```
foreach($Combo as $set=>$pCombo) {
$com = array($set=>(explode(',', $pCombo)));
    foreach($com as $set=>$com){
    $c = getVals($AssocArr, $com);
    print_r($c);
    }
}
```

print_r gives me:

```
array( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 ) 
array( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 )
array( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 )
```

Can anyone help me put it in the format:

```
array(0 => '3,1', 1 => '1,5', 2 => '3,5');
```

Thanks in advance for your help, and please let me know if you think there'd be a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is the [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key); this should do it:

```
$jersey = array('3','1','5','4');
$position = array('1','2','3','4');
$AssocArr = array_combine($position, $jersey);
$Combo = array('1,2','2,3','1,3');

foreach ($Combo as &$value) {
    $values = explode(',', $value, 2);
    $new_values = array_intersect_key($AssocArr, array_flip($values));
    $value = join(',', $new_values);
}

print_r($Combo);
```

It updates the `$Combo` array in-place and for each value, calculates the intersection with your associate array.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1M4Mc5)

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a completely different idea of what array_intersect_key would do. Thanks again!